# python flask server port deforced by ntpd

Tags: python, flask, port, ntpd

I have a rest server implemented by python with flask. And implement an *api* to restart `ntpd`. 
*The code test_flask.py:*

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess
import logging
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)


def run_shell_cmd(cmd):
    logging.info("run cmd: %s", cmd)
    try:
        rc = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
        if rc != 0:
            logging.error("Fail to run %s , rc: %s" % (cmd, rc))
    except OSError as e:
        logging.error("Fail to run cmd: %s" % e)
    return rc

@app.route("/restart_ntpd")
def restart():
    run_shell_cmd("service ntpd restart")
    return "Success!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s, %(levelname)s, %(filename)s:%(lineno)d, %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(
        format=LOG_FORMAT,
        level=logging.INFO,
        stream=sys.stdout,
    )
    app.run()
```

Then I operated as follow:

1. start flask server: python test_flask.py
2. curl "http://localhost:5000/restart_ntpd. Then ntpd restart & return    "success"
3. stop flask server: just use Ctrl+c to stop
4. start flask server again, it will raise a exception:

   > socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
5. use `sh $ netstat -ntlp | grep 5000`, the port was deforced by `ntpd`

I think the `ntpd` will use *port 123* in default. In my scene, why the *port 5000* is deforced by `ntpd`?  Is it the problem of flask?

Comment: what is the response of 'curl' cmd you ran? otherthan that sometimes it takes morethan a min time to close opened tcp ports even after respective process dead.

Comment: 'curl' will return 'success' and ntp server restart.   Wait a long time, the port still deforced by ntpd

Answer (score 1):

`ntpd` is not listening on TCP port 5000 itself, it's the environment where it is running - the process.

And that process is a child of your Flask server process, which opens a socket listening on TCP port 5000.

This socket is inherited in the child process, and since the `ntpd` process is a long-running one, it continues running with the socket it inherits from you, occupying the port 5000.

Check [how to deal with Python BaseHTTPServer killed,but the port is still be occupied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613194/how-to-deal-with-python-basehttpserver-killed-but-the-port-is-still-be-occupied) on how to prevent children processes from inheriting the socket.

Of course, first you have to find a way to customize the way Flask start the server.