# What is inherited by a child process?

Tags: java, linux, process, jpda

Does a forked process inherit any (server) ports bind from the parent process?
I have a java process which forks a child process and from `netstat -anpt |grep` I see that both parent and child are bound to the same port.
Is this possible? Is there a way to get arround this?

Answer (score 0):

> Does a forked process inherit any (server) ports bind from the parent process?

Its inherits the resources of its parent. This is the way the OS behaves.

> Is there a way to get around this?

The child has to close all the resources it doesn't need.  This is relatively easy to do in C but not simple in Java.  There might be a way to start a Java process with clean set of resources, but I don't know of a way to do this.

Comment: The problem I have is that I enable remote debugging port in the parent process `-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8989` and when I do `netstat` I see that both child and parent process are "bind" to this port.So it is not possible for me to debug.Do you have any ideas on what I could try to work arround this?

Comment: Why does this prevent debugging? Only one process will be accepting connections of that port.

Comment: Because the forked process is `C++` and it seems that it tries to deploy a server and endsup using that port.So `jpda` can not bind there.Does this sound reasonable assumption?This is what I understand that is happening

Comment: Which debugger is used to debug the C++ process? A different one, right?

Comment: @TheBlastOne:I am not trying to debug `C++` process.Only the java process.It seems that the forked process deploys a server and perhaps is bind to that port first?

Comment: BTW I assume you are using Runtime.exec?

Comment: Look at the FD_CLOEXEC thingy in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945865/process-started-from-system-command-in-c-inherits-parent-fds

Comment: @Jim that totally depends upon how you fork the child process. I wish you'd add the process-spawning call from your Java code that does the fork, then we might answer that.